# Атрибут post__in в в шорткоде WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Параметр `post_ids` оставляю пустым, предполагаю, что все посты должны выводиться и только если я указываю определенные ID, то они должны обрабатываться. Далее в выборке передаю эти значения массивом в `post__in`.

В результате у меня шорткод работает только если я передам значения в `post_ids`, что я не так делаю?

```
$atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'special',
            'posts' => '',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post_ids' => '',
        ),
        $atts,
        'zoo-specials'
    );

    // Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array ('post_type' => $atts['post_type'], 'posts_per_page' => $atts['posts'], 'orderby' => $atts['orderby'], 'order' => $atts['order'], 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post__in' => explode(',', $atts['post_ids']) ) );
```

Comment: Не надо указывать post__in вообще, если post_ids пусто

Comment: Сделать проверку и потом передавать переменную если не пустая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не надо указывать post__in вообще, если post_ids пусто. Делается это таким образом:

```
$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'special',
        'posts'     => '',
        'orderby'   => 'date',
        'order'     => 'DESC',
        'post_ids'  => '',
    ),
    $atts,
    'zoo-specials'
);

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => $atts['post_type'],
    'posts_per_page' => $atts['posts'],
    'orderby'        => $atts['orderby'],
    'order'          => $atts['order'],
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
);

if ( $atts['post_ids'] ) {
    $args['post__in'] = explode( ',', $atts['post_ids'] );
}

// Query.
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```